# discord.py how to wait for author message using wait_for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a command which waits for a user to reply to the bot, but I would like the bot to only accept the author's reply.

```
@client.command(name='numgame',
            brief='Guess a number between 1 and 100',
            pass_context=True)
async def numgame(context):
number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = 4
while guess != 0:
    await context.send('Pick a number between 1 and 100')
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)
    attempt = int(msg.content)
    if attempt > number:
        await context.send(str(guess) + ' guesses left...')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await context.send('Try going lower')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        guess -= 1
    elif attempt < number:
        await context.send(str(guess) + ' guesses left...')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await context.send('Try going higher')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        guess -=1
    elif attempt == number:
        await context.send('You guessed it! Good job!')
        break
```

My issue is that anyone can respond to "Pick a number," whereas I would only like the person who started the command to be able to respond.

I am not too sure what to try, but I think it may have something to do with arguments. I have no idea where to begin, though, so a solution would be appreciated! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Can we see your `check`?  You'll need to include the check for author in that function

Comment: @PatrickHaugh , I edited my post to show the whole command. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: You're passing `check=check` to `wait_for`.  What is `check`?

Comment: Ohhh, the check I am using is completely unrelated. Haha, how should I make it get the author only then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need rewrite your `check` so that it knows who the author is.  One way of doing this is to use a closure.  Let's say you have an existing check

```
def check(message):
    return message.content == "Hello"
```

You can replace this with a function that generates equivalent check functions with the author you want to check for injected into them

```
def check(author):
    def inner_check(message):
        return message.author == author and message.content == "Hello"
    return inner_check
```

Then you would pass the inner check to `wait_for` by calling the outer check with the appropriate argument:

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(context.author), timeout=30)
```

For your check this would be

```
def check(author):
    def inner_check(message): 
        if message.author != author:
            return False
        try: 
            int(message.content) 
            return True 
        except ValueError: 
            return False
    return inner_check
```

Comment: My existing check is:

`def check(message):
try:
            int(message.content)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False`
How should I incorporate the closure in this instance?

Comment: hey i know its been 2 years since this answer but i tried it and got:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: rolecheck() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: never mind, i forgot to pass self as the command is in a cog lol