# A typeracer in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm doing**: I'm trying to make a typeracer in discord.py, but first I'm trying to wrap my head around using `def check` and `def inner_check`.

**Problem**: As seen in the image below, when I type the correct sentence it still tells me that I'm wrong. There is no error as far as I have checked. I used the code from [this link here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723139/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-wait-for-author-message) which helped with the author input in case that helps.

[image: It's not working as I hoped it would]

**Code**:

```py
@client.command()
async def tr(ctx):
    starttime = time.time()
    C = "Just a nice little test"
    await ctx.send(f"Type: {C}")
    a = 1
    def check(author):
        def inner_check(message):
            return message.author == author and message.content == C
        return inner_check
    while a == 1:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author))
        if msg == True:
            a = a - 1
        else:
            await ctx.send("wrong")
    fintime = time.time()
    total = fintime - starttime
    await ctx.send(round(total,2),"seconds")
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but nesting these functions doesn't seem like it's needed.  https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/guessing_game.py

Comment: I think the problem is in `if msg == True`. Are you sure msg is set to True when you receive a message? Perhaps you could compare msg with C

Comment: @Doyousketch2 I have replicated this code before, and this code more often than not gives me problems, like how 'message' is not defined.

Comment: @steviestickman when I do `if msg == C` the exact same problem occurs. Despite a correct sentence, I'm being told it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically their Github example, just tweaked a bit.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import discord
import random
import asyncio

token = 'bot_token'

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as: ',  self.user.name,  self.user.id)
        print('--------------------------------------------------')

    async def on_message(self,  message):
        ##  no need for bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content == '!type':  ##  begin typeracer game with "!type" command

            answer = 'Just a nice little test'
            timer  = 5.0
            await message.channel.send(f'You have {timer} seconds to type:  {answer}')

            def is_correct(msg):
                return msg.author == message.author

            try:
                guess = await self.wait_for('message',  check=is_correct,  timeout=timer)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return await message.channel.send('Sorry, you took too long.')

            if guess.content == answer:
                await message.channel.send('Right on!')
            else:
                await message.channel.send('Oops.')

client = MyClient()
client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 3):

Based off of Doyousketch2's answer, I've written the other way to do it with the `@client.command` since it required a bit more tweaking. I've included the time taken (rounded to the nearest whole second) as well.

**What was changed**:

- Used `@client.command` rather than `if message.content == '!type'
- `message.channel.send` is now `ctx.send` here
- `message.author` was changed to `ctx.author`, since `message` would give an error of `name 'message' is not defined`

```py
@client.command()
async def type(ctx):
    starttime = time.time()
    answer = 'Just a nice little test'
    timer = 17.0
    await ctx.send(f"You have {timer} seconds to type: {answer}")

    def is_correct(msg):
        return msg.author==ctx.author

    try:
        guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=is_correct, timeout=timer)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.send("You took too long :(")

    if guess.content == answer:
        await ctx.send("You got it!")
        fintime = time.time()
        total = fintime - starttime
        await ctx.send(f"{round(total)} seconds")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Nope, that wasn't really right")
        fintime = time.time()
        total = fintime - starttime
        await ctx.send(f"{round(total)} seconds")
```