# yes/no confirmation after command in disord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python using the discord.py library. I need to know, how I can implement a yes/no confirmation after a command. For example, consider a 'ban' command that bans a user from the server, and can only be used by a moderator. After writing "!ban @user", I want the bot to reply "Ban @user?(y/n)" and if that very moderator replies with anything but a "y", the ban gets cancelled. How can I implement this? Something like this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.send("Ban @member?(y/n)")
    if get_confirmation():
        await member.ban(reason = reason)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Ban Cancelled")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, reason = None):
    await ctx.send(f"Ban {member.mention}?(yes/no)")
    @client.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def yes(ctx, member : discord.member, reson=None):
        await member.ban(reason = reason)
    @client.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def no(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Ban Cancelled")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `wait_for`.

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.send(f"Ban {member.mention}?(y/n)")
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m:m.author==ctx.author and m.channel.id==ctx.channel.id)
    if msg.content.lower in ("y", "yes"):
        await member.ban(reason = reason)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Ban Cancelled")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some digging i found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723139/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-wait-for-author-message). I hope it helps anyone with the same issue

Comment: If your question is a duplicate you can just delete it.

Comment: @takendarkk it might just help someone else :)