# Why is an error occurring in my bot? How can I solve it?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I have a project (given to me by myself) of making a quiz bot. I love pokemon a lot so I am making on it. The pokedex is a library I made that has the names of every pokemon. I have included time for afterward. Anyways,

```py
    import random
    import pokedex
    import discord
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    import os
    
    client=discord.Client()
      
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      msg=message.content
      if message.author==client.user:
        return 
    
      if msg.startswith("-q jname"):
        await message.channel.send("Unscramble these letters to create a name of a pokemon:")
        s=random.choice(pokedex.poke)["name"]
        await message.channel.send(''.join(random.sample(s,len(s))))
        p=""
        for i in s:
          if i=="(":
            p=p+i
          elif i==")":
            p=p+i
          else:
            p=p+"-"
          await message.channel.send(p)
          if(msg==s):
            await message.channel.send("Correct Answer")
          else:
            await message.channel.send("Wrong! The correct Answer is:")
            await message.channel.send(s)
    client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

This is my code. Now apparently the error I am having is that the quiz bot thinks that the command is the answer to the question. Please tell me how could I fix this.

This is how the error looks: (bot repeating wrong answer msg, and taking the command as answer)
[image: bot repeating wrong answer msg, and taking the command as answer]

Comment: Could you please show us the exact error code and what line it's on?

Comment: sure let me add it

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [discord.py rewrite | How to wait for author message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723139/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-wait-for-author-message)

The problem is, you are checking if the message starts with "-q jname", and then doing the check inside that command if the message is correct. Of course "-q jname" is incorrect, so you need to wait for the user to send another message, then use that message to do the check on.

```py
import random
import pokedex
import discord
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

client=discord.Client()
  

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg=message.content
  if message.author==client.user:
    return 

  if msg.startswith("-q jname"):
    def check(author)
        if message.author != author:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    await message.channel.send("Unscramble these letters to create a name of a pokemon:")
    s=random.choice(pokedex.poke)["name"]
    await message.channel.send(''.join(random.sample(s,len(s))))
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(message.author),    timeout=30).content
    p=""
    for i in s:
      if i=="(":
        p=p+i
      elif i==")":
        p=p+i
      else:
        p=p+"-"
      await message.channel.send(p)
      if(msg==s):
        await message.channel.send("Correct Answer")
      else:
        await message.channel.send("Wrong! The correct Answer is:")
        await message.channel.send(s)
client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

Comment: msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30), then you need to check msg instead of the original message. Also, define a check function similar to in the link I added at the start of my answer.

Comment: even though i wrote the correct answer it isnt now correct answer or wrong answer now

Comment: @KunshTyagi try it again with the new code i added, now it sets msg to message.content

Comment: It still isnt working, it doesnt take the correct answer and neither responds

Answer (score 1):

Firstly building on Oblique's answer with `bot.wait_for`, your code has the send functions within a for loop, and is sending a message every iteration.

I've attached my edited code below. Also it's good practise to use IDs, so if two channels (or users) have the same name it won't cause any errors

```py
import random
import pokedex
import discord
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content
  if message.author.id == client.user.id:
    return 

  if msg.startswith("-q jname"):
    def check(check_message)
      if message.author.id != check_message.author.id:
        return False
      return True

    await message.channel.send("Unscramble these letters to create a name of a pokemon:")

    pokemon = random.choice(pokedex.poke)["name"]
    await message.channel.send(''.join(random.sample(pokemon, len(pokemon))))

    try:
      msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)
    except:
      pass
      
    if msg.content.lower() == pokemon:
      await message.channel.send("Correct Answer")
    else:
      await message.channel.send("Wrong! The correct Answer is:")
      await message.channel.send(pokemon)

client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

Comment: The code that oblique and you, and mine all send the following error msg:
https://imgur.com/a/uxy5yNo I cant understand why?

Comment: Oh that's simple, that just means that when the timeout has reached 30 seconds, that error is raised. A simple try and except can get that fixed

Comment: Also I noticed the check was slightly off, fixed it though

Comment: @KunshTyagi if this answer worked, could you mark it as completed?