# Accept a second input based on the first one in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to have a command that deletes all the messages in a channel.

```
@pip.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):
    if amount == "all":
        await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to delete all messages in this channel?")
        async def yes(ctx):
            if ctx == "yes":
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100000000)
```

This is my code for doing that.

It sends me the message asking if I'm sure that I want to delete all messages, but after that, it does nothing when I type in "pip yes" (pip is my prefix) How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py rewrite | How to wait for author message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723139/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-wait-for-author-message)

Comment: That helped solve most of my problems, thank you very much!

Comment: if you want to clear all the messages in the channel it's better to clone the channel using [`TextChannel.clone()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.clone) and then deleting the original one

Answer (score 0):

You should take a further look at [client.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for). It's in in build function for discord. Sheers!

```
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):
   if amount == "all":
      await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to delete all messages in this channel?")

      def check(message):
         if message.author == ctx.author:
            return ctx.author == message.author # Or just return True

      try:
         answer = await client.wait_for('message', timeout = 20.0, check = check)
         if answer.content == "yes":
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100000000)
         else:
            # Do something

      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
         await ctx.send('Timeout')
```

Comment: I tried implementing your code and most of it worked very well, but even when I type in "yes" it runs the else code and not the if code. Could you help me figure out why that is? Thank you very much for your help, the documentation you linked it helping me a lot!

Comment: `@pip.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):
   if amount == "all":
      await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to delete all messages in this channel?")

      def check(message):
          if message.author == ctx.author:
            return ctx.author == message.author

      try:
         answer = await pip.wait_for("message", timeout = 20.0, check = check)
         if answer == "yes":
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1000000)
         else:
            print("failed")

      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
         await ctx.send('Timeout')`

Comment: My bad, it should be `answer.content`. Feel free to upvote and mark my answer! Sheers mate!