# discord.py adding mentioned users to list

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make disposable register system by using list which makes adding the discord user to list when you mentioned it but when i try to get user input from message it fails

```
@bot.command()
async def gameset(ctx,playernum:int):
 if playernum <= 10:
     await ctx.send('player 1 "<assign @player" mention yourself like this!')
 else:
     await ctx.send('maximum 10 player!')

num = 1
while num < playernum:
    
    playerlist = []

    @bot.command()
    async def assign(user):
        if user == discord.User.mentioned_in(message=user):
            listadd = user
            playerlist.append(listadd)
            await user.send(f"player {num + 1} mention yourself!")
        elif user != discord.User:
            await user.send("not user")
        else:
            await user.send("go fix it dumb")

    if playerlist[num - 1] == discord.User:
        num = num + 1
    else:
        await gameset.send("problem with the listing")
```

also i think this is not the only problem i tried like this too but then my mention/user percaption logic failed i think

```
@bot.command()
    async def ata(user : discord.User):
        if not user:
            await user.send("go fix it dumb")
        else:
            listadd = user
            playerlist.append(listadd)
            await user.send(f"player {num + 1} mention yourself!")
```

I've tried with @bot.event but i made more progress with @bot.command so if this is able to do with @bot.event i would be pleased if you guys help me understand how can i do with event but command is sufficient too.

Edit: I tried using wait_for() command like this:

```
num = 1
while num < playernum:
    playerlist = []

    def check(msg2 : discord.member):
        return msg2 == discord.mentions

    msg2 = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    # player = await bot.fetch_member(msg2.id)
    if msg2 == discord.member:
        player = str(msg2.id)
        listadd = player
        playerlist.append(listadd)
        await ctx.send(f"player {num + 1} mention yourself!")
        num = num + 1

    else:
        await msg2.send("go fix it dumb")
```

and i think it worked but now i have another problem which is

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "@!id>" is not found

i get this when i try to mention someone

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack! Instead of using another `bot.command`, have you tried using [`bot.wait_for`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726649/14420546)? It would allow your bot to watch for messages sent by other users if you program your check correctly. Also, you cannot put a command within a command.

Comment: Oh i searched much but i didn't come across bot.wait_for so i just noticed i'm on it