# await client.wait.untill.ready is used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I'm coding a bot for Discord, and I was wondering if this command is still used? Because it gives an error when running

`await client.wait.untill.ready`

The error:

`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'wait'`

Comment: There's no method `client.wait.untill.ready()`, neither is there an attribute `wait` of the object `Bot`. The syntax is wrong. You're either looking for [`Bot.wait_until_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready) or [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) if you're looking for a way to wait for a user to react or reply to a message or something similar for making 'self-roles'-like commands. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726649/16136190.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I will try here