# AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'wait_for_message'

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

I'm having this problem

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'wait_for_message'`

I want to know how to make a random number generator commmand. And it waits for author a message.

This is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio
import random

@client.command()
async def randomnum(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Type a number")
  num1 = await ctx.wait_for_message(author=ctx.author)
  await ctx.send("Type a second number")
  num2 = await ctx.wait_for_message(author=ctx.author)
  
  try:
    numb = int(num1)
    numb = int(num2)
    value = random.randint(min(num1, num2), max(num1, num2))
    await ctx.send(f"You got {value}.")
  except:
        await ctx.send(":warning: Please use positive integers")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py how to wait for author message using wait\_for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723139/discord-py-how-to-wait-for-author-message-using-wait-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `client.wait_for`. Note that since num1 and num2 will store a message object after the `wait_for`, you need to re-set them to the content of their message object values. Try out the following:

```py
@client.command()
async def randomnum(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Type a number")
  num1 = await client.wait_for(event='message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
  await ctx.send("Type a second number")
  num2 = await client.wait_for(event='message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

  num1 = num1.content
  num2 = num2.content
  
  try:
    numb = int(num1)
    numb = int(num2)
    value = random.randint(min(num1, num2), max(num1, num2))
    await ctx.send(f"You got {value}.")
  except:
        await ctx.send(":warning: Please use positive integers")
```

You can also set an optional `timeout` parameter which specifies how long you want to wait to read the message.
Documentation: [`wait_for(event, *, check=None, timeout=None)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)