# how to make client.wait_for look at one person

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im making a guessing game and im trying to use the  `client.wait_for` function for it but the problem is this function looks at all the messages being sent after you have run it but I want it to only look at one person's messages. I also tried this:
`if guess.author != user: return`
which did work, it would stop the code if someone else talked when you are using the bot but if someone speaks on another server when you are using the bot it will still be stopped.
if it could only read one person's messages it would be nice.
my full code:

```
        user=message.author
        number = random.randint(1, 100)
        await message.channel.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, you have 7 guesses, guess.')
        for guesses in range(0, 7):
            guess = await client.wait_for('message')
            if guess.author !=user:
                await message.channel.send("sorry game ended cus someone talked mid game.(this can happen if people talk even if not in this sever)")
                return
            if int(guess.content) < number:
                if guesses == 6:
                    await message.channel.send("Too many guesses, try again.")
                    await message.channel.send("The number I was thinking of was " + str(number) + ".")
                    break
                else:
                    await message.channel.send("Higher!")
            elif int(guess.content) > number:
                if guesses == 6:
                    await message.channel.send("Too many guesses, try again.")
                    await message.channel.send("The number I was thinking of was " + str(number) + ".")
                    break
                else:
                    await message.channel.send("Lower!")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("You got it! You guessed " + str(guesses + 1) + " times.")
                break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py how to wait for author message using wait\_for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723139/discord-py-how-to-wait-for-author-message-using-wait-for)

Comment: not really, i wanted it to cheek only one person

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a check to your `wait_for` like this:

```py
guess = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author.id == user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom check allows you to actually use custom checks, you can use any method returning a bool, that way you can even use things unrelated to the bot itself, python is the limit.

```
def check(msg):
    return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
```

---

```
msg = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=check)
```